# Website -> Count Button Clicks and never reset

Tags: javascript, java, html, database, web

Holaaa

I wanted to create a simple website containing a button. If I press the button 5 times, it says 5. When I refresh the page, it should still say 5.
And when You load the page, it also says 5 and you can go on clicking.

I know how to build a counter for ONE session and one user, but I have nooo idea how to implement it to be stored "online".

I know that I need to implement a database to store the value and load the latest click-value once the website is opened but I dont know where to simply start

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question. Also: JavaScript is a different language from Java. You should edit your tags.

Comment: You could use "cookies", "localstorage", or a back-end file that stores the current count. You could even use a "get url" but why bother. In other words there are many ways to do what you want to do. What have you tried and if any, show your code?

Comment: @GetSet 

This is my first experience with a database
I dont really know where to start -> I created a website (diepstats.com) for a small Online Game I am playing. I also managed to create a small API to load some data from the players.

But now I want to include a little game (count clicks and never reset) on my page to get a simple start with a database -> because it only needs to store one variable (the button click count)

I think I cant really send you any code because (regarding databases) I`ve got none

Comment: @GetSet
> I opened a MYSQL Database on my provider (Ionos). Now I am figuring out how to store a variable / update it and load it on the page

Comment: Going with a database is not necessary for your current project. A db will increase the complexity of your learning experience. But if you want to go that route, of course do so. As an alternative you can use the local storage by Alejandro Gonzalez below. This will circumvent the need to know who the user is via a db setup, since the "local storage" is on the user's device. A "cookie" solution will also be comparable.

Comment: However if your design goal is to know the total clicks no matter who the user is, you also don't need a full blown db (e.g. SQL). You could write the count via your server side code to a plain text file. BASICALLY: when a click event occurs, ajax to your sever, your server side script reads the current count, +1 it, rewrites that file, and done.

Comment: There is some code that should be involved to check if the file that stores the count, is not currently being written to. Essentially to make "concurrency" possible. This is also easy. Simply make a "lock" file before writing to it, and if another process encounters that "lock" file, make it wait some N milliseconds. Ahh well this is sounding complex as I write it but really its not.

Comment: @GetSet

damn that sounds really hard for me :D But I appreciate it, I never would have thought about these things ... I will look into all these words and topics right now.

and yes, for my idea I dont care who the user is -> I just want an "All-Time" Clicker Count

Comment: Alright I'll post a basic code example that you can modify to make it work for how you want it to. In *proof* that it's not complicated. But wait I can't do that because your question doesn't have a server-side language tagged. You will **need** a server side stack setup. I cant advise one over the other but I do have experience in PHP. Look into getting that setup on your dev machine. XAMPP is a good option.

Comment: @GetSet

I am so sorry- i tired to look "server-side" / "Side stack setup" up but it seems more complicated than anything I've done :,D Wserver-side language tagged -> what is this exactly for? Something so you can enter you`re code? -> btw whatever you are trying to do -> you dont need to do that - dont wanna waste your time

Comment: I don't know what OS you are using is why I suggested you look into it. Also I dont know what "server" side language you will be deploying to. But on your local machine you can use whatever. And from there when you actually go live, just pick a hosting provider that supports the server side language you chose.

Comment: Your search terms were generic and is why it came up like that with too many options. I'd suggest going directly to https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html to get XAMPP installed on your dev machine (your computer). From there you will be able to write server side code in PHP. When you want to test "live" and for deployment, pick a hosting provider that supports PHP out the box.

Comment: But you wont need a "hosting provider" to learn and get experience. Once you install XAMPP, your computer itself will be the "server" which you can test out code by directing your browser to "localhost".

Comment: @GetSet
I think I understand you now. 
> I started a statistics website for a game I am playing (diepstats.com is what I created so far) -> I developed that with HTML / CSS / little bit of JS. I also got XAMPP to test out my simple database (I am using the provider IONOS which gives me space to store my HTML/CSS/JS files and gives me a database) -> I also connected "diepstats.com" to that database, but its useless atm... With PHP I got the connection but now my problem is to store / upload and download the latest "CLICK COUNT" / display it on my HTML code

Comment: So my thought was that my next step is this:
Ive got a button at the website -> With JS I am counting the clicks and now I have problems -> The live/latest click-count variable needs to be uploaded to the database for the next user etc...
If this is even the right approach. You guys also said I should look into the LocalStorage thing. Will do that

Comment: Well since I'm just learning now you already have a PHP setup, I will post a answer to doing the click count. Give me a moment.

Comment: @GetSet

I dont know if you need to know this but XAMPP doesnt work with my server, IONOS (the provider) only accepts databases-calls from its own website. So I couldnt connect my "Localhost" /XAMPP with that database. I had to upload the .php file on IONOS to access the database.

No idea if this information is needed.

Comment: I used IONOS on several projects and they support PHP out the box. And of course your local db will have to be migrated to a 3rd party to work.

Comment: @GetSet
Hey! I kinda got a solution now (not perfect) but this is my first attempt -> I got a .php sub-page and for each "refresh" it adds +1 to the database (and displays the number on the page). So my "button" is just a refresh-button. -> But I still cant figure out, how to include a normal button on my .html page which adds +1, and where you can also SPAM the button and dont have to wait for the page refresh

Answer (score 1):

You can use localstorage to persist the count.

Example when the page starts:

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('miGato');
```

Example to save the count:

```
localStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan');
```

The documentation is:

[Localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Window.localStorage,
Syntaxis

```
var cat = localStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan');
```